# How to run multiple tomcats against the same Database with load balancing

Tags: java, tomcat, database-connection, load-balancing

Please suggest what are different ways of achieving load balance on database while more than one tomcat is accessing the same database?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Do you want to establish a database cluster or just connect a Tomcat cluster against one database?

Comment: It is actually connect a Tomcat cluster against one database. Actually connect more than one tomcat to a single database.

Answer (score 3):

This is a detailed [example](http://www.zulutown.com/blog/2009/02/16/java-ee-load-balancing-with-tomcat-and-apache/)  of using multiple tomcat instances and an apache based loadbalancing control

Note, if you have a hardware that would make a load balancing, its even more preferable way as to me (place it instead of apache).

In short it works like this:

- A request comes from some client to apache web server/hardware loadbalancer
- the web server determines to which node it wants to redirect the request for futher process
- the web server calls Tomcat and tomcat gets the request
- the Tomcat process the request and sends it back.

Regarding the database :
 - tomcat itself has nothing to do with your Database, its your application that talks to DB, not a Tomcat.
Regardless your application layer you can establish a cluster of database servers (For example google for Oracle RAC, but its entirely different story)

In general, when implementing application layer loadbalancing please notice that the common state of the application gets replicated.
The technique called "sticky session" partially handles the issue but in general you should be aware of it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Mark, Can you please explain a few more ways of how to balance connections between the database and my tomcat servers? Thanks..